# Command and Parameters are being parsed but only the first if statement is working

Tags: c#

I am trying take a command and some parameters from a textbox and use them to draw some shapes, the command and parameters are being parsed  but only the top if statement is actually doing anything

```
        void Commands(string Command, int X, int Y)
        {
            if (Command.Equals("line"))
            {
                MyCanvas.DrawLine(X, Y);
            }
            else if (Command.Equals("Rect"))
            {
                MyCanvas.Rectangle(X, Y);                  
            }
            else if (Command.Equals("Reset"))
            {
                MyCanvas.Reset();
            }
            else if (Command.Equals("Circle"))
            {
                MyCanvas.DrawCircle(X);
            }
            else if (Command.Equals("Tri"))
            {
                MyCanvas.DrawTriangle(X, Y);
            }
            else if (Command.Equals("Red"))
            {
                MyCanvas.Red();
            }
        }
```

Comment: line is the unique command lowercase. It's correct?

Comment: I've used .ToLower when i split the text box so as far as i know it should be ok

Comment: then all the commands must be lowercase

Comment: What I am understanding from your question "only the top if statement is actually doing anything" is this mean only first if condition is hitting and executing MyCanvas.DrawLine(X, Y);. But others are not executing based on your text box command value. Am I correct ? If it is then always check in this way Command.ToUpper().Equals(). It will not matter what string data you are sending it will convert to upper case and then validate.

Comment: can't believe it was that obvious it's been a long day